# How to get two results

Tags: sql

I want to delete some data from one table, and the same data that I deleted I want to insert to another table.

Comment: Simply insert the data in the target table first, then delete it from the source table. But maybe you don't really need two tables at all. What about a flag in the table to indicate whether it belongs to record set 1 (table 1 so far) or set 2 (table 2 in your scenario).

Answer (score 0):

i would do it in two ways

1. you can query the data you want to delete and insert it to the table you want then delete it.
2. you can create trigger that is fired up when deleting data from the first table, its job is to put the data to the other table before its deleted.

   CREATE [OR REPLACE ] TRIGGER trigger_name 
   {BEFORE} 
   {DELETE} 
   [OF col_name] 
   ON table1 
   [FOR EACH ROW]
   BEGIN 
     insert [data] into table2
   END;

Answer (score 0):

That's not how SQL works.

But you can make three SQL statements:

1. Select data you'd like to delete
2. Delete data
3. Insert result from (1.)